# I want to export array data to csv file

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to export array data into the csv file, I created a file tset.csv and trying to write the data into the file using following code

This is my array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [pgm_name] => General services ) 
    [1] => Array ( [pgm_name] => Department of education ) 
)
```

Code:

```
$filename = 'test.csv'; 

header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename"); 
header("Content-Type: application/csv; ");
// header("Pragma: no-cache");
// header("Expires: 0");

$file = fopen(FCPATH.'/uploads/'.$filename, 'w');
fprintf($file, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));
$header = array("Program Name"); 
// fputcsv($file, $header);
foreach($printdata as $printdata) { 

   fputcsv($file,$printdata); 
}
fclose($file);

exit;
```

in csv file I'm getting error like this

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message:  fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array   string given

Filename: controllers/Frontdoor.php

Line Number: 3516

"

Backtrace:

"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: fputcsv($file,$printdata["pgm_name"]);

Comment: Foreach($printdata as $row) { fputcsv($file, $row["pgm_name"]); }

Answer (score 0):

Please check "foreach($printdata as $printdata) {".

You should use

```
foreach($printdata as $data) { 
   fputcsv($file,$data); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. Hopeful its helpful for you

```
$output = fopen("C:/xampp/htdocs/data.csv",'w') or die("Can't open C:/xampp/htdocs/data.csv");
header("Content-Type:application/csv"); 
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=$filename"); 

fputcsv($output, array('pgm_name'));
foreach($printdata as $value) {
    fputcsv($output, $value);
}

fclose($output) or die("Can't close C:/xampp/htdocs/data.csv");
```